# Partition rows where dates are between the previous dates

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have the below table.

I want to identify overlapping intervals of start_date and end_date.

`*edit` I would like to remove the row that has the least amount of days between the start and end date where those rows overlap.

Example:

`pgid 1 & pgid 2 have overlapping days. Remove the row that has the least amount of days between start_date and end_date.`

Table A

```
id   pgid  Start_date    End_date      Days
 1    1    8/4/2018      9/10/2018      37
 1    2    9/8/2018      9/8/2018        0
 1    3    10/29/2018    11/30/2018     32
 1    4    12/1/2018     sysdate        123
```

Expected Results:

```
 id   Start_date    End_date     Days
 1     8/4/2018      9/10/2018    37 
 1     10/29/2018    11/30/2018   32  
 1     12/1/2018     sysdate      123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `lead` and `lag`:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN END_DATE > LEAD (START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY START_DATE) THEN 1
WHEN START_DATE < LAG (END_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY START_DATE) THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END OVERLAP_FLAG
FROM A
```

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking `exists`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.start_date < t.start_date and
                                t2.end_date > t.end_date and
                                t2.id = t.id 
                         )
             then 2 else 1
        end) as overlap_flag
from t;
```

Comment: @MrJohn . . . Is there a reason that you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Not sure the answer meets my needs. I'm currently reviewing in more detail.